# how to apply only 1 coupon code when there are multiples coupon codes

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, promotions

I am running magento 1.9 and i have multiple coupon codes on site. how to make that only 1 coupon code apply on cart? any body know how to apply on 1 coupon on cart?

Answer (score 0):

just go to Promotions->shopping cat price rules ->Action ->Stop Further Rules Processing ->Yes
and all is set